# How to print a variable containing html content as string?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am trying to show a user entered data from a text box to a html div. User entered data can be anything.
If the data contains html contents , it gets screwed up as the content is not shown as string rather than html elements.

eg

```
let text = "<h1>World</h1>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

I want output as `<h1>World</h1>` instead it is showing

## World

How to fix this ?

Comment: Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` so that it doesn't render the string as html.

```js
let text = "<h1>World</h1>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```